# Why can't I run two USB serial adaptors on the same machine?

Tags: serial-port, usb, adaptor

My work involves interacting with legacy hardware that uses serial ports. I often have to monitor more than one serial line, and for the purpose I have a couple of the common USB serial adaptors. When I connect both of them to the same (Windows 10) machine, irregularities show up. Both ports show up in device manager, but only the first one that I plug in to the USB connector works. The other one indicates port not open when I try to send data via RealTerm.

I have also seen the situation where when I plug the second adaptor in, its port comes up, but the one for the other adaptor disappears. Does anyone know a way that two devices can happily coexist on the one machine?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have used a hub and multiple USB-to-RS232 adapters (with FTDI or Prolific chips) for many years, and have not encountered similar issues.  Maybe it's the equipment that you're using?

Answer (score 0):

Just ion case this helps anyone in the future......

The problem seems to be caused by the fact that one of the adaptors was coming in via a (powered) USB hub. When I liberated another native port on the machine so I could host both serial adaptors directly, everything worked fine.

Not worth hunting the cause down, a solution is at hand.